# Exact match with double quotes in Elasticsearch 7

Tags: elasticsearch

I used to use double quotes to achieve "exact match" (here it does not mean exact match on term level, "Nike Air" should match "nike air", but should not match "Nike Air Force") in older ES version (2.x, 5.x):

```
GET some-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "brandName": "\"Nike Air\""
    }
  }
}
```

So I only get "Nike Air" and not "Nike Air Force". But the query is not working under ES 7 - "Nike Air Force" is also returned. How can I achieve the same under ES 7?

Here is the mapping definition of `some-index`:

```
{
  "some-index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "brandName" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html this should help

Comment: Can you show the mapping for `some-index` please?

Comment: @RussCam Sure updated.

Answer (score 2):

[Match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) query searches for tokens. So it searches for token nike and air in documents

If you  intend to do exact match use [term](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) query  on keyword field

```
 "query": {
    "term": {
      "brandName.keyword": "Nike Air"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, sorry for confusion here the "exact match" does not mean exact match on term level, "Nike Air" should match "nike air", but should not match "Nike Air Force".

Comment: It is case insensitive. If using term query document should have exact words(case insensitive) and in same order. In case of match query tokens are checked ex. it will look up for word nike / air , whichever document contains them will be returned.